# Can't open my laptop after halting

Tags: sudo, shutdown, reboot

I'm using Ubuntu 20.4 and I wrote the command "sudo systemctl halt" and now the power button light is on but I can't really open it

Comment: Hello. There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.4

Comment: Oh I guess I meant 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Poweroff your system. Wait 10 seconds. Then poweron.

'Halt' is a not a form of suspend, it *terminates* the system without telling it to poweroff.

For a laptop, a suspend or shutdown command is usually more convenient.

Comment: you mean poweroff from the power button?

Comment: Yes. If your system is halted, then your disks are unmounted and the OS is not running. This is the one safe time to hold the power button.